# How to ensure an asynchronous call is executed before returning from a function in Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

I am new to mongoose and in order to prevent ASYNC OF HELL I came Across an npm package called [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback). I have used the `async.series` of the [async](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) npm package and my code looks in the given format given below

```
var userId=1234
function findUser(callback){
  user.findOne({userId:userId}).exec(function(err,userData){
         //Some Logic
   var schoolId=123;
   var schoolName=findSchool(123);     
   findStudents(schoolName);

   var schoolId=1234;
   var schoolName=findSchool(123);     
   findStudents(schoolName);

   callback(null);
  });
}

function findSchool(schoolId){
 school.findOne({schoolId:schoolId}).exec(function(err),schoolDetails){
    //Some Logic  
  });
    var schoolName="XYZ High School"
    return(schoolName);
}

 function findStudents(schoolName){
  student.findOne({schoolName:schoolName}).exec(function(err),studentDetails{
    //Some Logic  
  });
 }

 async.series([findUser],function(err){
     // for Error Handling
    }
```

Here I am using an async series function to prevent the ASYNC of HELL. I am calling `findUser` function in the async series call which is find the user details from my `User` model using the `userId` and then I am calling the `findSchool` function *inside* the `findUser` function which finds school details for the given `SchoolId` in `School` model. Once the function returns the call I am trying to find the students based on a particular `schoolName` using the `findStudents` function on the `Student` model.

The process is repeated for a different `schoolId`. My Issue comes when I call the `findSchool` function. Since it has a asynchronous call (`findOne`) on the `school` model, I am able to return the value of the `schoolName` even before the `findOne` is completed for the model.

Is there a way to ensure that the given function `findSchool` doesn't return the value of the `schoolName` until the `school.findOne()` has completed successfully? Just to add more clarity I *don't want* to my return statement *inside* the `findOne` of the `findSchool` function.

Comment: use async waterfall -  https://github.com/caolan/async#waterfall

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should still use `async` but you need `async.waterfall` for that. Here is what you need to consider:

A main method to call your `async` function:

```
var getInformation = function(){
  async.waterfall([
    //Array of your functions in order, we will be back here later
  ], function (err) {
       if(err){
         console.log(err);
       }else{
         console.log('Everything OK!');
     }
  );
}
```

Then you need your functions to be `async` friendly, that means you should use callbacks and give your data from one function to another. Something like this:

```
function findUser(callback){
  //Do something
  if('Everything OK'){
    callback(err, yourData); //err should be null if everything is OK and yourData should be the data that you wanna use in your next function. e.g. schoolId 
  }else{
    callback(err); //Something was wrong, "err" should have something different to null
  }
}

function findSchool(callback, schoolId){ //Note that we receive the parameter schoolId here but not in the first function
  //Do something
  if('Everything OK'){
    callback(err, yourData); //err should be null if everything is OK and yourData should be the data that you wanna use in your next function. e.g. schoolName 
  }else{
    callback(err); //Something was wrong, "err" should have something different to null
  }
}

function findStudents(callback, schoolName){
  //Do something
  if('Everything OK'){
    callback(err); //err should be null if everything is OK if this is the last function maybe we don't need to send back more data from here 
  }else{
    callback(err); //Something was wrong, "err" should have something different to null
  }
}
```

Then you should call your functions in your main method:

```
var getInformation = function(){
  async.waterfall([
    findUser,
    findSchool,
    findStudents
    //Note that there is no need to tell the functions the parameters they are sending or receiving here
  ], function (err) {
       if(err){
         console.log(err);
       }else{
         console.log('Everything OK!');
     }
  );
}
```

And that's it, you have 3 functions that should be executed one after the other and no callback hell is needed.

Comment: hi Gepser What if I have multiple calls from my findUser to my findSchool function. will async waterfall there? Suppose I have multiple SchoolIds for which I place a for loop in my findUser function will async waterfall help in that scenario?

Comment: @shubhamagiwal I am glad it help you. And you should read `async` doc, you could do anything related with workflows with it.

Answer (score 0):

Async.each or async.waterfall should do the trick, I think.

The main thing here is that you're using return statements in your async functions, which will return before the async function has actually completed, and thus they won't pass along what you need.

You have to use async functions and callbacks for this. You can still have your functions separated like you want in your code, but you'll have to add callback functions instead of returns.